# How to Store Hex Values (i.e. Raw Bytes) in WebAssembly Data Segment

Tags: javascript, webassembly

I have this situation:

```
(module 
  (memory (import "js" "mem") 1)
  (data (i32.const 0) "\aa"))

fetch('index.wasm').then(function(response){
  return response.arrayBuffer()
}).then(function(bytes){
  return WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, {
    js: {
      mem: memory
    }
  })
})
```

I am trying to place "raw bytes" into the data segment in WebAssembly according to the [docs](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/text/values.html#strings). But getting this error in the browser (not getting a compilation error with `wat2wasm`):

```
Uncaught (in promise) CompileError: AsyncCompile: Wasm decoding failed: expected section length @+37
```

I've tried different variants such as this, which doesn't throw an error but when I log the output there is no output (I would expect it to say "0" or something:

```
(data (i32.const 0) "\00")
```

I try other things such as this:

```
(data (i32.const 0) "\a0")
```

But it gives the same error. Any help would be appreciated.

As an example to further demonstrate how to use the raw bytes feature, it would be helpful to know how to represent a number like `123`. I do the following and get strange results when I serialize to an Uint8Array -> String in JavaScript:

```
(data (i32.const 0) "123")
```

So wondering how that should look in terms of hex codes. `123` in hex is `0x7B`, so maybe:

```
(data (i32.const 0) "\7b")
```

But I think it needs to be two hex numbers, or not quite sure. Anyway if that's too complicated or distracts from the first part of the question no need to address it.

Comment: The error message you quote is from decoding the *binary* format, but you're asking about the text representation. Your examples all look fine. How did you produce the binary from that?

Comment: `wabt/out/clang/Debug/wat2wasm index.wat -o index.wasm` from https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt. The binary is `0061 736d 0100 0000 020b 0102 6a73 036d
656d 0200 010b 0701 0041 000b 01aa`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested with your example and it seems to work fine for me in latest Chrome (67.0.3396.99) and FF (61.0.1).

**index.wat**

```
(module
    (memory (import "js" "mem") 1)
    (data (i32.const 0) "\aa"))
```

Then I produced a binary with `wat2wasm index.wat` which matches the bytes you mentioned in the comment above:

**index.wasm**

```
00 61 73 6D 01 00 00 00 02 0B 01 02 6A 73 03 6D 65 6D 02 00 01 0B 07 01 00 41 00 0B 01 AA
```

Then I loaded this via a simple HTML page:

**index.wasm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

        fetch('index.wasm').then((response) => response.arrayBuffer())
        .then((bytes) => {

            const memory = new WebAssembly.Memory({
                initial:10,
                maximum:100
            });

            return WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, {
                js: { mem: memory }
            });
        })
        .then(function (module) {

            console.log(module);
        })
        .catch((err) => {

            console.log(err);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The console output looks correct in that it parsed and loaded the WebAssembly module correctly:

**Console screenshot**

[image]

Regarding the second part of your question, you can encode 123 in memory using the expression exactly as you stated it `"\7b"`. Here's an example:

**index.wat**

```
(module
    (memory (import "js" "mem") 1)
    (data (i32.const 0) "\7b"))
```

If we log out the first index in our memory in the JS we can see it's 123:

**index.html**

```
const memory = new WebAssembly.Memory({
    initial:1,
    maximum:1
});

fetch('index.wasm').then((response) => response.arrayBuffer())
.then((bytes) => {

    return WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, {
        js: { mem: memory }
    });
})
.then(function (module) {

    console.log(new Uint8Array(memory.buffer));
})
.catch((err) => {

    console.log(err);
});
```

**console output**

[image]

Hope this helps you somewhat!

Comment: Thank you so much, will have to check this out. Maybe it was my version of `wat2wasm`.

Comment: Yes perhaps, I wondered the same. I actually wondered if the literal value `123` shouldn't be allowed judging from the grammar in the docs. I opened an issue on wabt repo, hopefully someone knows: https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt/issues/881

Comment: Interestingly if you use `wasm-as` from Binaryen it treats `123` as the string `"123"`.

Comment: Thanks @AndreasRossberg do you have a pointer to that bit so I can educate myself?

Comment: @MattHarrison, http://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/text/modules.html#data-segments

Comment: Thank so much @AndreasRossberg